# Circular Map View in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

Trying to constrain a map view into a circle. Is there a way I can do some masking magic or something?

Any pointers or links are helpful.

Comment: forget about map, try to create a circular view first!!!! There are many tutorial about masking uiview in different shapes!!!

Comment: "Any pointers or links are helpful" Doing a little research before asking would have been even more helpful. This kind of question has been answered a gazillion times on SO.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try:

```
mapView.layer.cornerRadius = 999 
mapView.clipsToBounds = true
```

*Note: this will probably cover the legal notice in the bottom left corner which might result in your app being rejected from the store.*